# Applicative for a user defined type

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm trying to write Applicative for this type

```
data Choice a = ColumnA a | ColumnB a
```

I wrote a Functor instance:

```
instance Functor Choice where 
  fmap f (ColumnA a ) = (ColumnA (f a) )
  fmap f (ColumnB a ) = (ColumnB (f a) )
```

Now I want to write Applicative where `ColumnB` is considered "a correct value" and `ColumnA` is considered to be some kind of an error.

I tried

```
instance Applicative Choice where
    pure             =  ColumnB  
    ColumnB f  <*>  r  =  fmap f r
    ColumnA f  <*>  _  =  ColumnA  f   --- this does not work
```

How can I make it work ?

Comment: You need to look at the types: at the left hand you have a `Choice (a -> b)`, on the right hand a `(Choice a)`, and it expects a `Choice b`. So returning a `Column A` is indeed not an option.

Comment: What do you mean "this does not work"? What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rename your data constructors to express your intent properly, as

```
data Choice a = Bad a | Good a
```

Your `Functor` instance keeps the taint on the values,

```
instance Functor Choice where 
  fmap f (Bad  x)  =  Bad  (f x) 
  fmap f (Good x)  =  Good (f x)
```

so let's just do the same for the Applicative, without being skimpy with our clauses:

```
instance Applicative Choice where
    pure              x  =  Good    x     -- fmap f == (pure f <*>) is the Law
    Good f  <*>  Good x  =  Good (f x)
    Good f  <*>  Bad  x  =  Bad  (f x)
    Bad  f  <*>  Good x  =  Bad  (f x)
    Bad  f  <*>  Bad  x  =  Bad  (f x)
```

As was pointed in the comments, this interprets `Choice a` as isomorphic to `Writer All a`, meaning, `Choice a` values are really just like `(Bool, a)` with `(False, x)` corresponding to `Bad x` and `(True, x)` corresponding to `Good x`. Naturally we only consider values to be `Good` if everything in their provenance was `Good` as well.

Comment: [*idiomatic*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/idiomatic): `data Choice a = Bad a | Good a deriving stock Generic1 deriving (Functor, Applicative) via Idiomatically Choice '[RightBias Id]`

Answer (score 2):

If `ColumnA` is considered some kind of error, you can not let it wrap an `a` value. Indeed. The idea of `(<*>)` is that it takes a `Choice (x -> y)` and `Choice x`, and returns a `Choice y`. But if you have a `ColumnA` that wraps a function of type `x -> y`, and you have at the right hand a `Choice x`, then it thus should return a `Choice y`, not a `Choice x`.

What you could do is define a type with two type parameters, for example:

```
data Choice a b = ColumnA a | ColumnB b
```

then you only perform a mapping over the `ColumnB b` data constructor:

```
instance Functor (Choice a) where
    fmap _ (ColumnA e) = ColumnA e
    fmap f (ColumnB x) = ColumnB (f x)
```

and then we can define an `Applicative` instance as:

```
instance Applicative (Choice a) where
    pure = ColumnB
    ColumnB f <*> ColumnB x = ColumnB (f x)
    ColumnA e <*> _ = ColumnA e
    _ <*> ColumnA e = ColumnA e
```

Such instance for a `Functor` and `Applicative` however already exist: this is how it is defined on the [**`Either`** data type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Either).

Comment: I'm not going to answer because I think your approach is probably the correct one.  Another interpretation is that `Choice a` is isomorphic to `Writer Any a`.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem  - I tried running your code but it does not compile. It does not like the  "(Choice a)"

Comment: @GilShafriri it's true, it suffered from a subtle type behavior when using `@`-bindings.  Fixed.

Comment: @Tim this is obviously not the right approach for the given type, because it changes it to a completely different type. So I've added that answer you hinted at.

Answer (score 0):

I made a package for deriving `Applicative` for sum types:[*idiomatic*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/idiomatic).

`Choice` can be biased towards the left or the right, if it is biased towards the left then `ChoiceA` is the pure constructor and combining A an B defects to `ChoiceB`:

```hs
{-# Language DerivingVia #-}
{-# Language DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# Language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# Language DataKinds  #-}

import Generic.Applicative
import GHC.Generics

data Choice a = ColumnA a | ColumnB a
  deriving 
  stock (Show, Generic1)

  -- pure :: a -> Choice a
  -- pure = ColumnA
  -- 
  -- liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> (Choice a -> Choice b -> Choice c)
  -- liftA2 (·) (ColumnA a) (ColumnA a') = ColumnA (a · a')
  -- liftA2 (·) (ColumnA a) (ColumnB b)  = ColumnB (a · b)
  -- liftA2 (·) (ColumnB b) (ColumnA a)  = ColumnB (b · a)
  -- liftA2 (·) (ColumnB b) (ColumnB b') = ColumnB (b · b')
  deriving (Functor, Applicative)
  via Idiomatically Choice '[LeftBias Id]
```

and right-bias means `ChoiceB` is the pure constructor and combining A an B defects to `ChoiceA`:

```
  -- pure :: a -> Choice a
  -- pure = ColumnB
  -- 
  -- liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> (Choice a -> Choice b -> Choice c)
  -- liftA2 (·) (ColumnA a) (ColumnA a') = ColumnA (a · a')
  -- liftA2 (·) (ColumnA a) (ColumnB b)  = ColumnA (a · b)
  -- liftA2 (·) (ColumnB b) (ColumnA a)  = ColumnA (b · a)
  -- liftA2 (·) (ColumnB b) (ColumnB b') = ColumnB (b · b')
  deriving (Functor, Applicative)
  via Idiomatically Choice '[RightBias Id]
```

Comment: How does it handle types with 3 alternatives?

Comment: You continue adding sums to the list, one of the example from the documentation shows deriving idiomatically via 
`[LeftBias Initial, LeftBias Inner, RightBias Outer, RightBias Initial]`. Even though the direction may change (as in this example) the order must always be linear and coherent: a constructor cannot pass over an adjacent constructor and two constructors cannot differ when reached differently (this is a restriction of the applicatve structure I believe). I may add it to the library to give more control over this.